# run a shell command if emr activity fails in aws data pipelines

Tags: amazon-data-pipeline

In AWS Data Pipelines, how can one run a shell command ONLY if a certain activity such as an EMR activity fails?  I can see the "onFail" option but that only runs an amazon action which is defined as: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-actions.html

Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to run an activity on failure of another activity is not supported. You could however issue a SNS notification on failure. You can invoke a lambda function on an SNS notification. See here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html

Comment: This sounds promising.  I'll be checking it out and will follow up

Comment: I tried it out, and was able to have AWS Lambda to parse my sns message to get the desired onfail behavior.  So it works. Thanks for the help!  Aplogies that i forgot to followup. It would be great if AWS can integrate this behavior into pipelines itself